# VB.NET: Is there a way to reduce the lag of loading a huge list of text lines to a listbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox

I am using file.readalllines to read the file into a string, then using listbox.items.addrange and splitting by vbcrlf to insert the items. Is there a way to reduce the lag it causes for loading huge lists?

Answer (score 4):

Given that the file is large enough to cause unresposiveness by reading it atomically, it would seem that you should be doing the reading in a separate thread.

A thread-pool item should do the job here. Try this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
     using(var streamReader = new StreamReader("foo.txt"))
     {
         string line;
         while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
             listBox.Invoke(() => listBox.Items.Add(line));
     })
```

(My VB.NET is a bit rusty, so if someone could convert that, that would be helpful.)

However, the fact that you have to call `Invoke` to cross the thread-boundary to update the GUI will mean that your performance will actually *decrease*, though at least you'll get normal responsiveness with the UI!

The other obvious option is to use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), which is designed to perform long tasks in the background in UI applications. However, I'm not sure it offers any advantages in this case, and a simple thread pool item would be significantly simpler and allows you to do everything inline.

Answer (score 1):

Use the BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods; this will disable redrawing of the listbox temporarily and can speed up the process of populating it.

```
ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
' fill the list using Items.Add or Items.AddRange '
ListBox1.EndUpdate()
```

Comment: This will help with speed, but not responsiveness of course. If the file is sufficiently large, there's no real point to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fill the listbox using another thread. This will avoid the "hang", leting the user interact with the another form controls.
You can also load itens partially instead of load all data at once.

Answer (score 1):

Use a BackgroundWorker and load the file in a seperate thread. Be careful about adding the lines to the ListBox from the thread. You'll need to post the items from the correct thread.

Answer (score 1):

> file.readalllines to read the file into a string

No! File.ReadAllLines reads into a string *array*.

> splitting by vbcrlf

So this is already done for you: you're doing a bunch of extra work for nothing.

Comment: Yeah, that was the part where I was wondering what he really is doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you may want to read the data into an array of strings in another thread, I would suggest that populating the ListBox should probably be a single action on the UI thread.  If the number of items is so large that the delay merely for populating the ListBox with an AddRange would be unacceptable, it would seem unlikely that users would be able to usefully interact with the control in the first place.